# Why Kubernetes Not Able to access ip by the Domain Name?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-dns

i am trying to ping website by the Domain Name but pod is not able to ping the machine
but when i tried with ip address it is able to ping the machine.After i add the ip with
domain name in the hosts file on /etc folder it is able to ping the machine by domain name.
is there any solution without doing that.

Comment: There are ways to additional records via configmap of coredns. Answer is already present in this site.

Comment: You're trying to connect to a server process that speaks ICMP?  Can you provide a code example showing the client code, and the errors accessing it one way but not the other?